# APOO tem utilidade hoje?

Tags: orientação-a-objetos, engenharia-de-software, uml, projeto-de-software, metodologia

Fui lá na *software engineering.SE* e [perguntei](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/376731/which-ooad-methodologies-are-prominent-today) o que tem de metodologia de APOO (Análise e Projeto Orientados a Objeto) proeminente hoje (aqui no Brasil não tem muito, mas lá nos EUA, vai que... né?), como tinha no passado, nos anos 90, época das *method wars* que culminaram com a criação da UML. Antes da pergunta ser fechada disseram que a parte OO tem muito menos ênfase hoje que nos anos 90 e que o que existe de mais próximo hoje é a técnica de *design* que tira proveito da OO chamada *Domain-Driven Design*.

Acho que é isso mesmo, porque não se fala mais em UML como se falava nos anos 2000 (digo, não se vê mais nos anúncios de emprego), e as equipes não colocaram nada no lugar, a impressão que tenho é que hoje no máximo se faz desenvolvimento ágil com design *ad hoc*.

Minha pergunta é: APOO tem utilidade hoje? Por que não se usa? É porque não dá o retorno esperado? Ou o pessoal não conhece? Ou não se interessa?

O que se faz no lugar? O que dever-se-ia fazer no lugar?

Difícil responder? Eu entendo, lá fecharam por *"not sure what you're asking"*.

Comment: @Maniero Recuperei, está aqui: [https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/376731/which-ooad-methodologies-are-prominent-today](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/376731/which-ooad-methodologies-are-prominent-today)

Comment: Relacionado :) https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/1049/to-what-extent-should-uml-be-covered-in-the-context-of-a-degree

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O que importa é entregar produto que atende requisitos, entre eles que:

- seja facilmente usável (o que envolve muitas coisas, entre elas a velocidade certa)
- resolve o problema corretamente
- permita evolução com tranquilidade
- outros pontuais.

Tem diversas técnicas para se fazer isso, mas escolher uma fechada, e que tem que fazer tudo o que está no "manualzinho" não me parece prudente.

Análise e Projeto Orientado a Objeto não me parece ser uma técnica muito fechada em certo aspecto, ou seja, não parece ser um manualzinho, pelo menos não por um livro dos anos 80 que tenho (ou tinha) sobre o assunto específico.

Pra falar a verdade criar um projeto e já saber que será orientado a objeto me parece uma bela de uma tendenciosidade.

## Agile

Eu costumo dizer, até palestrar, que quase toda conceituação do que usamos na computação fora criada até os anos 60 e quase toda tecnologia que usamos hoje fora criada até os anos 70. Tem bem poucas exceções. Quase tudo é pequena evolução no jeito de usar ou reciclagem do que existia. Na minha opinião, muito em função de marketing, é recriado para ter um produto novo. Vejo hoje pessoas falando de Agile quando isso é muito simples, e no fundo é só uma questão de bom senso, mas as pessoas deram um jeito de ganhar muito dinheiro com o carnaval que fizeram.

A tal da [guerra de métodos](https://www8.cs.umu.se/kurser/TDBC31/Overheads/L6_new.pdf) tem muito a ver com isso, foi uma *corrida do ouro* para ver quem consegue impor o seu padrão e ficar rico com isso. Não inventaram nada novo, só embalaram de um jeito diferente.

## UML

Por sorte UML meio que morreu (tem gente que não percebeu ainda), sempre foi uma bobagem (não que sirva para nada, mas não é melhor que o que já existia salvo um detalhe ou outro), como ferramenta criada é desnecessário. Foi a época que a indústria queria vender as tais [ferramentas CASE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer-aided_software_engineering) que as pessoas falavam que ia acabar com o programador e eu dava risada, mesmo sendo um bobão inexperiente de 20 anos, e eu tinha argumento, não era chute.

O que sobra? A boa e velha análise e projeto de sistemas, alguns orientados a objeto. Cada época com roteirozinhos novos de como fazer, às vezes usam gráficos ou ferramentas diferentes pra ajudar visualizar o projeto, e em alguns casos dentro de um determinado *bias* para fazer de um jeito específico conforme a moda do momento. Até porque elas não sabem o que fazer e recorrem à fórmulas que alguém venda para eles.

## Porque não é mais usado

A pergunta afirma porque não usa, mas falta evidências que não usam. Provavelmente não usam o termo. Se está falando de algum roteiro específico pode ser que dê para falar se souber de qual está falando. Qual é a opção? "Meter o lôco" e entregar qualquer coisa? Alguns acham que Agile é assim, alguns acham que se planejar qualquer coisa não é ágil. Lamento por essas pessoas. Nem vou entrar no mérito que alguns produtos são terríveis justamente por adotarem Agile, não importa se certo ou errado (quando dá errado falam que não era o Agile certo, quando as vezes o problema nem era esse). Dizem que UML é Agile, sendo que ele é algo extremamente burocrático e um passo normalmente desnecessário que traz pouco benefício. Pra falar a verdade vi muito projeto Waterfall mais ágil que projeto Agile usando UML e outras ferramentas inadequadas.

## Conclusão

A minha conclusão que apenas não está na moda usar esse termo. E isso não é nada diferente do que as pessoas, mesmo que informalmente, as vezes rabiscando um papel, fazendo um protótipo em código, enfim, ágil é isso, é fazer, é atender a demanda.

Nenhuma metodologia ensina fazer certo, é experiência, é habilidade da pessoa olhar o todo, procurar cada detalhe, não deixar escapar nada, criar um olhar novo, repensar o que está encontrando ali, entender o que precisa ser feito, o que terá de dificuldade futura. E o que costumo dizer, em orientação a objeto costuma ser mais difícil fazer porque você tem que enxergar o objeto e boa parte de suas relações de forma muito apropriada, enquanto que paradigmas ou orientações que prezam pela composição são mais flexíveis.

## OOP

Por isso que se diz:

- em OOP a cada mudança no projeto que exige uma nova ação você tem que mudar vários objetos
- em procedural/funcional você tem que mudar cada função sempre que adiciona um novo objeto no modelo.

Aí vem a pergunta: o que é mais comum na vida real de projetos de software, depois da criação inicial, adicionar objetos ou funções novas para o objeto? Por isso defendo um *approach* híbrido. E cada vez mais me convenço que OOP em domínio de negócio deve ser bem limitado, ele é melhor para mecanismos, onde o programador tem mais controle e teoricamente consegue prever mais o que pode acontecer.

## DDD

Não sei se DDD tem algo a ver com isso (pela pergunta original no SE.SE), nem que se encaixe nessa conversa, mas tenho conversado com gente que usa e é show de horrores relatado por eles. E geralmente quem incentivou diz que eles não souberam fazer direito, só que fizeram o curso do cara e receberam certificado dele. E pelos meus estudos tem uma coisas terríveis na metodologia que eu não tinha percebido, embora eu ainda ache a ideia geral legal, o problema está nos detalhes.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Uma dúvida, "a velha análise e projeto de sistemas" se refere a qual destes conceitos? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systems_analysis_and_design

Comment: Pra falar a verdade tenho dúvidas se todos esse são diferentes. Tem cara de duplicidade de assunto, mas se for tudo diferente são detalhes tão pequenos que nem saberia dizer, sei que um ou outro não se aplica.

Answer (score 1):

a resposta do @Maniero foi perfeita, estou apenas incluindo uma simples observação, que li recentemente em um artigo e complementando com minhas palavras:

Atualmente, os requisitos estão mudando muito rápido, tornando inviável realizar um levantamento de requisitos, mapeamento de processos e documentação dos mesmo em um tempo hábil de projeto. Com isso grande parte dos projetos está se utilizando do "Ágil", mesmo sem nem ter a noção do que é isso, baseando todo o desenvolvimento nas estórias do usuário ou simplesmente no processo descrito pelo mesmo. 
O grande problema é que, a estória do usuário é limitada, pois o usuário nem sabe o que quer, ou o processo mapeado não reflete a realidade, ou até mesmo não há processo definido, gerando várias alterações nas regras dos sistemas depois de pronto, o que pode causar um impacto muito grande no **Custo X Tempo X Qualidade** do projeto.

Um projeto de 1 mês, se houvesse um levantamento de requisito e mapeamento dos processos, talvez levaria de 2 a 3 meses, dependendo da complexidade, tornando-o inviável para a estratégia empresarial. A conclusão do colega @Maniero, descreve bem.

> "E isso não é nada diferente do que as pessoas, mesmo que informalmente, as vezes rabiscando um papel, fazendo um protótipo em código, enfim, ágil é isso, é fazer, é atender a demanda"

Answer (score 1):

## APOO é uma ferramenta. Qual o uso pretendido?

APOO é uma forma de ver um problema e também de ver/conceber uma solução. Conceitos como classe, herança e vários outros pertinentes à orientação a objetos são instrumentos empregados para modelar, registrar e analisar este problema, assim como uma solução (código) proposta.

Se, ainda hoje, há publicação constante de livros acerca de orientação a objetos (seja análise e/ou design), assim como de livros acerca de linguagens orientadas a objetos, bem como o desenvolvimento de linguagens que se posicionam como orientadas a objetos, então entendo que há evidências de que APOO possui um espaço.

Isto não pode ser confundido com uma sugestão de que se deve fazer uso de APOO. O seu contexto deve orientar a escolha da estratégia a ser adotada tanto para análise quanto para projeto. Noutras palavras, dado que análise e projeto não são opcionais, a questão é como você fará isto e, dentre as possibilidades, está APOO.
Adicionalmente, se o software a ser construído, por exemplo, faz parte de um sistema crítico, então você terá que considerar um método formal de desenvolvimento em vez de APOO convencional.

Em resumo, não há como fazer uma escolha prévia. Dentre as estratégias de análise e design, você adotará uma compatível com o seu contexto, poder ser APOO, pode não ser.