# Quando e por que usar dicionários de dados?

Tags: banco-de-dados, engenharia-de-software, arquitetura-de-software, dicionário

Eu já tinha lido essa resposta (abaixo) e hoje a li novamente, e em ambas ocasiões o trecho destacado me chamou a atenção:

> [O DRY é para evitar redundâncias, certo? - Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/120932/86952)
>
> Por isso eu uso [dicionários de dados](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_dictionary) de forma estendida (não só na definição clássica) há muitos anos. No dicionário da aplicação tenho todos os fatos da aplicação em um só lugar. Mudando ali, estou mudando em tudo o que preciso. Dependendo da tecnologia usada até o código pode estar nesse dicionário, mas na maioria não dá para fazer isto. Aí existem técnicas específicas para ligar os fatos com o código.

Confesso que eu não tenho muita intimidade com o conceito de dicionários de dados e não tenho costume de usa-los na prática, por isso surgiu a dúvida de quando e porque deveríamos usa-los.

Mas o que me chamou mais a atenção foi a parte que diz: "*de forma estendida (não só na definição clássica)*". Quais seriam as formas de aplicabilidade de dicionários de dados?

Comment: Vixi, agora? A resposta é longa, preciso ver se consigo responder :D Acho que farei aos poucos :D

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Do que estou falando aqui

Vamos definir que quase todo mundo que fala de dicionário de dados está se referindo ao *schema* do banco de dados ou pelo menos algo parecido, ou seja, é como você modela o banco de dados e tem uma série de metadados que vão ajudar o sistema do banco operar naquele modelo, eles vão definir o que pode ou não pode fazer ali, diz quais são as tabelas, índices, colunas, as chaves, os tipos de dados, as restrições, os gatilhos, etc. Para quem não sabe o que é o termo tem aí uma visão já conhecida do tal do *data dictionary*, ou seja, um mecanismo que tem todas as definições e regras dos seus dados.

O uso estendido que eu falo naquela resposta é um conceito que vai além do banco de dados, é você usar o [dicionário de dados](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_dictionary#Middleware) para toda sua aplicação. O termo aqui usado é sobre desenvolvimento de software, sobre programação e não só sobre modelagem de dados. Até falaremos de dados, o nome não é usado à toa, porém entendemos todos os objetos ou artefatos (ou ativos) do desenvolvimento como sendo dados do desenvolvimento.

Esse uso, até onde eu sei, começou forte em ERPs nos anos 70. Me parece que que o primeiro que fez isso de forma ainda discreta foi o COPICS (Communications Oriented Production Information and Control System) da IBM. Eles pegaram a ideia do dicionário de dados do SGDB e colocaram algumas coisas que o ERP precisava. Daí um monte de ERP começou a copiar (aliás, o Sistema da Ampulheta Permanente no seu início era uma cópia quase exata do COPICS). E cada vez foram adicionando mais coisas, o que acabou virando outra coisa, mas o nome ficou. Eu aprendi o conceito com esse nome.

Pensando bem, isso deixou de ser um dicionário de dados puro. No mínimo é um dicionário de dados de aplicação. E nem é só sobre dados, então fica mais preciso e mais simples chamar de **dicionário de aplicação**. Pois bem, é disso que estou falando aqui.

Há alguns anos era fácil achar na internet informações sobre o que estou falando, agora exige muito mais esforço, a quantidade de ruído aumenta muito quando um termo é usado em mais de um contexto e um deles se sobressai em relação ao outro. Não temos um termo formal e universalmente aceito sobre o assunto, então para buscas tem que ser por "dicionário de dados" e filtrar manualmente o que é sobre o DB ou a aplicação.

É possível ter um dicionário de dados corporativo, afinal o conceito se aplica a qualquer tipo de dado ou processo, não só em TI. Mas aqui falarei apenas sobre o seu uso no desenvolvimento de software.

Tanto o conceito do *database* quanto do corporativo tem relação com o que estou falando aqui, mas são objetivos diferentes e com ativos diferentes.

## O que é e para que serve

Ele serve para gerenciar complexidade ao mesmo tempo que dá flexibilidade, e de forma extremamente produtiva, dando um poder muito grande ao programador e até ao usuário (o que pode ser questionável).

O custo inicial de criar um dicionário próprio é grande e feito porque quem não entende pode não dar os resultados esperados. E para aplicações que mudarão pouco não tem tanta vantagem, o ganho se dará ao longo do tempo conforme suas mudanças podem ser feitas com muito mais confiança e de forma rápida. O DD em inglês ou DdD em português (mais um DDD :P) vem para te dar produtividade e robustez.

Em algumas implementações pode realmente ajudar na produtividade, em outras pode prejudicar. Não use essa tecnologia em sistemas triviais, nichados, que não tenha um grande volume de objetos, que não precisa de mudanças constantes em regras de negócios (constante mesmo, não estou falando de mudanças eventuais como ocorre na maioria dos softwares não LOB).

Pra mim a principal vantagem é justamente o que está na resposta original, é sobre o DRY, que eu considero o princípio de desenvolvimento de software mais importante que existe. De tudo o que se fala sobre gerenciamento de complexidade, de manutenibilidade e até outros conceitos que se pregam em engenharia de software é o DRY que mais dá tudo isso. E algumas técnicas "modernas" que vendem por aí pregam desistir dele, um dos motivos que sou crítico dessas técnicas. São técnicas que pregam o aumento da complexidade para gerenciar a complexidade. Elas são novas, não comprovadas e contra o que foi comprovado por décadas.

Não vou negar que alguns consideram o DD uma técnica complexa, e ela é mesmo. Mas se bem feita essa complexidade extra pode se tornar transparente ao sistema. De fato é uma plataforma que está sendo criada, não se engane. E já fica claro que não serve para sistemas pequenos ou simples demais. Mas se torna mais importante em sistemas que as pessoas desenvolvem hoje em dia, que têm complexidade excessiva e principalmente redundância excessiva. Onde tem camadas tem complexidade excessiva, e para voltarmos ao DRY só o dicionário de dados para salvar.

O AD (*application dictionary*) tem a ver com manter todas informações sobre a aplicação em um só lugar, todas mesmo, até a documentação. DD é muito [Agile](https://agilemanifesto.org/), mas vai procurar se algum proponente de Agile ouviu falar. Você mantém a documentação dentro da aplicação e "garante" que a documentação muda junto com a aplicação

- Foca na necessidade das pessoas e não no processo de desenvolvimento de software.
- Obtém o software com qualidade com quantidade reduzida de ferramentas.
- O usuário pode participar ativa ou passivamente, mas sem o ruído técnico que ele não entende.
- Responde à mudança de forma ágil em interações curtas por natureza, afinal se é mais fácil fazer a mudança a interação fica mais curta e previsível, portanto mais gerenciável.

## Gerenciamento de projeto

E possivelmente diminui a quantidade de pessoas envolvidas resolvendo o problema do [The Mythical Man-Month](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Mythical_Man-Month), inclusive envolvendo o cliente de forma mais direta.

Muito do que falo aqui está lá nesse livro que é a referência canônica sobre gerenciamento de projetos. Eu não invento nada, só organizo e interpreto as coisas que estão bem estabelecidas. Algumas eu não falo explicitamente, mas o DD ajuda em quase todos os pontos que o livro toca. Eu recomendo a leitura desse e de todos os clássicos da nossa área. Chega a dar pena das pessoas novas entrando na área que nunca nem ouvirão os nomes desses livros porque elas estão preocupadas apenas com a tecnologia do dia.

Ele:

- ajuda a controlar o andamento do projeto de forma natural e quase transparente, e permite ver todo histórico (se bem feito, sempre digo isso),
- ajuda diminuir a necessidade de profissionais altamente competentes de programação (embora para criar o DD precisa-se deles),
- reduz-se a necessidade de testes, de avaliações, e até ficar pensando demais em arquitetura em cada mudança que se faz, sendo mais fácil garantir a **integridade conceitual**, algo que poucas pessoas falam e é das coisas mais importantes no desenvolvimento de software.

O AD é um conceito, mas que acaba se tornando uma ferramenta. Geralmente ele é gerenciado através de um *framework*, ou até um SDK, por ser uma biblioteca bastante integrada com sua aplicação e/ou ferramentas externas que ajudam gerenciar o dicionário. Isso é uma plataforma. Mas é diferente de outros *frameworks* que as pessoas usam tanto?

Ele seria tão obscuro e rechaçado (até por omissão) se um grande *player* lançasse algo assim? Por exemplo, se o Visual Studio viesse com uma ferramenta e o .NET a suportasse dentro dele, será que o DD não teria uma adoção massiva, até mesmo onde não deveria? (de fato criaram isso, o [Visual Studio LightSwitch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ff851953(v=vs.140)?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397), algo feito por quem não entendia bem o que precisava ser feito, por isso não deu certo).

Ele não é diferente de usar um ORM, aliás ele substitui com vantagens um ORM, afinal a inteligência toda passa a estar no dicionário. Acaba a dicotomia entre *code-first* ou *model-first*, é *dictionary-fisrt* e único, é [uma só fonte da verdade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_source_of_truth#SOLID_&_Source_Code) (em alguns casos pode se transformar em [versão única da verdade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_version_of_the_truth)). Não deixe de ler também sobre o [`System of record`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_of_record), uma das bases do DD, mas aplicado ao desenvolvimento.

Enfim, é um achado e quem o conhece e pode suportar isso, não quer nunca mais largar.

## Críticas

Mas claro que ele não está longe de críticas. Embora algumas justas, a crítica que mais ouço (e pouco, porque as pessoas não conhecem e não querem conhecer o tal do dicionário de dados de aplicação, as pessoas só querem aprender o que está na moda, o que está sendo falado por todo mundo, que não é o caso do assunto aqui), e bastante válida, é que ele cria o chamado [Second-system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second-system_effect) ou [Inner-platform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner-platform_effect). Isso de fato não é bom, mas é um preço que tem que se pagar para ter uma série de benefícios. Mas não se engane, as pessoas fazem coisas tão complexas hoje em dia que acabam criando a mesma complexidade por acidente, e sem tantos benefícios. Pelo menos no AD você sabe que está criando complexidade. As pessoas vivem criando essas aberrações sem perceber, isso é especialmente verdade em "aplicações web".

Sugiro a leitura do artigo da Wikipedia que fala sobre plataforma internalizada, porque grande parte do que se fala de boa prática e das arquiteturas e padrões de projetos que se prega hoje em dia acabam caindo nela. Preste atenção! O problema é que as pessoas não percebem isso.

Entre outras coisas que citei no texto vou exemplificar aqui o [NoSQL](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/96409/101), mas podem ser coisas mais específicas como o uso errado de exceções. E há controvérsias quando o artigo diz que uma máquina virtual sempre é uma boa escolha e uma *inner-platform* aceitável. Se isso é verdade, o AD certamente é, porque ele traz muito mais benefícios, chega a ser algo próximo de uma bala de prata, tamanho o ganho (depois do custo inicial amortizado, por isso seria melhor ter algo pronto, o que não é fácil fazer para atender todas demandas, o que por sinal é um dos problemas que o SQL tem e por isso fez nascer o NoSQL).

Quem não tem experiência cairá em uma série de armadilhas, que eu já caí. Por exemplo entrar no [Greenspun's tenth rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greenspun%27s_tenth_rule). Eu aprendi sobre o DD (agora chamando de AD) em um grande projeto de uma grande empresa do ramo de ERPs, e que nunca funcionou bem, mas que sempre foi muito útil assim mesmo. O problema é que ele foi feito sem ter conhecimento do que deveria ser um AD, sem pensar no futuro, e era usado mais como instrumento de marketing do que de engenharia.

Vejo o mesmo em produtos como o [Dynamics](https://dynamics.microsoft.com/en-us/?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) da Microsoft, só pra ficar em um exemplo nominal (até acima da média) de quem fez o AD sem entender o que ele é (outros fizeram pior ou nem possuem algo parecido), sem planejamento, para atender uma necessidade no meio do projeto e não como requisito inicial, e chamando de DD, o que já conceitua-se errado na largada.

Não recomendo fazer em produção antes de entender bem o assunto ou se um terceiro fizer um **produto** bem pensado para você consumir. Eu não faço esse porque não sei como financiar ou comercializar isso (ainda mais que hoje esse tipo de coisa só teria sucesso se fosse código aberto), é o problema de ser engenheiro. Uma coisa eu tenho certeza: tentar fazer como quase todo produto de hoje em dia produzirá um resultado bem ruim. Ele não pode nascer como um [MVP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_viable_product), esse foi o erro dos ERPs atuais. E tenho medo do monstrengo que pode se tornar para atender a necessidade de todo mundo, por isso teria que pensar em uma solução, que provavelmente se tornaria um *third-system*, o que pode ser bem ruim.

Claro que todas essas críticas cabem à muita coisa que se usa hoje sem pensar. Tome por exemplo a [lei do envolvimento do software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jamie_Zawinski#Principles): se fosse levada a sério, deveríamos usar só Assembly.

Eu posso citar o fato de exigir bons programadores para implementá-lo como uma dificuldade dele. Também exige um mínimo de competência para o seu uso, mas isso é requisito quase universal, talvez ele sofra um pouco mais em certo nível de utilização porque a pessoa precisa entender seu funcionamento, e as relações entre tudo, mas não consigo ver como seja muito diferente de códigos normais. De fato pode exigir programadores menos experientes para cuidar de alguns ativos mais isolados, que antes não seriam.

É necessário a montagem do que se chama **equipe cirúrgica**, onde cada pessoa tem sua especialidade. Há o cirurgião chefe (arquiteto do AD), os demais cirurgiões (engenheiros dos domínios específicos), e os auxiliares que cuidam de apenas um aspecto da cirurgia (programadores que codificam os ativos mais detalhados), esses que realizam até mesmo coisas menos relevantes, ou que são fáceis de serem realizadas, mas que precisam ser bem-feitas.

Eu não sei se compensa fazer em qualquer software (bom, qualquer já é exagero, claro que alguns são obviamente descartados). Mas você sabe? Como? Eu falo de experiência, elimina-se aí opiniões sem fundamento, a pessoa só achar que não serve. Eu tenho experiência fazendo isso em ERP plataforma e em linguagem dinâmica. Eu tenho alguma experiência fora disso, mas de forma limitada. Será que funciona bem em C# em um ERP interno de uma empresa? Será que funciona fora de um ERP? Eu queria tentar pelo menos o primeiro, eu acho que minha experiência tornaria isso um sucesso e se alguém quiser me contratar para esse tipo de projeto estou disponível :D.

Obviamente que não dá para ter medo de se tornar uma plataforma quando o objetivo é ser uma plataforma. Mas será que compensa ter uma plataforma quando o objetivo não era esse?

## Que problema ele resolve

Hoje é comum termos a documentação, e pode ser várias instâncias, o banco de dados, e cada vez mais estamos vendo ter vários deles para a mesma coisa, e ter algumas camadas da aplicação, que pode ser o modelo, o controlador e a visão, isso no servidor e depois no cliente de novo a mesma coisa, e pode usar linguagens diferentes, e pode ter outras camadas, serviços, contextos ou outras necessidades, e ter cliente GUI, web, "API" ou até CLI. Todo campo novo envolve analisar e, potencialmente, mudar uma quantidade enorme de locais, e não pode esquecer nenhum. E pode ser que outros departamentos, que não o seu, ou até o usuário quando ele tem o privilégio de fazer isso, têm usado em algum lugar que você nem sabe. Sem controle de todos ativos e onde eles são usados não tem como dar certo.

Em era de microsserviço e DDD, só para citar duas pragas novas que inventaram, o uso do dicionário de dados deveria ser obrigatório. Eu já falei antes aqui no SOpt que uma implementação melhor do DDD pode torná-lo mais palatável e viável para muitos casos. E isso provavelmente passa pelo AD. Não estou falando de algo que renega a modernidade, mas facilita sua adoção, se realmente ainda for necessário.

AD torna OOP "obsoleto". Não que não possa usar essa forma de pensamento em mecanismos específicos do software, que, aliás, é [onde OOP brilha](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/344486/101), mas o seu uso para definir todo o software não faz muito sentido, inclusive porque o dicionário de aplicação tende a seguir um modelo mais relacional de fazer as coisas (se parece com o conceito de banco de dados, mas não é ele em si). AD pode eliminar a necessidade de OOP e todos os padrões de projeto normalmente associados a esse modelo, mantendo a complexidade bem mais controlada.

De fato, OOP é uma forma simplificada e ingênua de se fazer um AD que foca no objeto e não nas relações. Pensa bem o que é mais importante e que pode dar mais problema, é o objeto ou a relação que esses objetos têm entre si? DD foca na relação, ainda que tenha tudo o que OO tem também. Ah, ele encapsula e abstrai muito mais.

## Tipos de dicionários:

- Dicionário de aplicação ativo

  Geralmente implementado com linguagens ditas dinâmicas, ou pelo menos em linguagens ditas estáticas mas com poderosos mecanismos de reflexão.

  Essa forma permite que o usuário configure na própria aplicação o que ele quer que mude e tudo se reflete ali, na hora, durante a execução. Parece ótimo, certo? Não pela minha experiência.

  Usuários tendem a fazer errado, e essa liberdade cria uma situação em que praticamente voltamos ao modelo de gestão de dados e processos complexos através de planilhas (quem já viu isso sabe o problema que é). Mas essa aparente liberdade impõe alguns limites do que pode se fazer no dicionário. Acho que o maior erro dos ADs é justamente querer ser uma ferramenta de usuário, e de alguma forma, de marketing. Brilha os olhos de todo mundo, ninguém vê a dor de cabeça que será.

  Há um custo relativamente elevado de performance, principalmente se fizer todas verificações possíveis que são necessárias para dar robustez.

  As pessoas sobrevalorizam demais a necessidade de mudar o comportamento do software em tempo de execução, e de fato os ERPs que eu conheço que usam AD na prática precisam reiniciar por um monte de motivos, tanto o cliente (até mesmo web) quanto o servidor.
- Dicionário de aplicação passivo

  Em geral implementados como geradores de código. Hoje gosto mais disso, talvez porque meu viés agora seja em cima de linguagens estáticas.

  Ele é usado como um mecanismo do desenvolvedor e não do usuário. Você tem um catálogo de objetos do seu sistema para facilitar a visão geral e controlar a mudança. Mudando algo nele é preciso regerar a aplicação que será mandada para o usuário. É possível inclusive gerar versões diferentes dependendo do usuário.

  Dessa forma se livra do usuário se tornar parte da engenharia do produto e deixa as mudanças nas mãos de quem, teoricamente, tem mais condições de pensar nas mudanças. O usuário pode participar passivamente da mudança.

  Outro ganho muito grande é o da performance, afinal muito do que seria decidido em tempo de execução é resolvido na geração do código. Sem falar na simplificação, já que a complexidade é abstraída pelo gerador de código, nada muito diferente de muitas soluções que você talvez use e nem perceba.

  Essa é uma forma de *[scaffolding](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/119731/101) on steroids*.

## Funcionamento

Como ele não pegou tração no mercado não há definições muito formais de como chamar as coisas. Farei aqui um resumo informal, nem há espaço para ser um manual, nem tenho esse fundamento todo tão sólido para que se torne algo tão canônico.

Ele lembra muito o dicionário de dados de um banco de dados, mas ele envolve todo o software.

Em essência temos um catálogo de objetos que serão usados na aplicação. Algumas pessoas preferem chamar de artefatos, mas provavelmente precise de um nome diferente porque não é nem uma coisa nem outra, pelo menos não pode se confundir com os conceitos usados [em programação](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_(computer_science)) ou [em engenharia de software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artifact_(software_development)) (dá pra ver que o termo é ambíguo até aí), ou muito menos [em arquitetura de negócios](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enterprise_architecture_artifacts), talvez seja parecido com o [uso em UML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artifact_(UML)), então vou chamar de ativos, que é um termo usado em *games*, mas acho que para esse contexto é adequado.

Por sinal, há semelhanças entre UML e o AD, e talvez o AD devesse ser o que UML prometeu e não entregou, por excesso de burocracia e falta de resultado concreto a entregar, fica sendo só mais uma camada no desenvolvimento, que vai contra a base do que é Agile, o que eu [já critiquei antes](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/321826/101) e já [mostrei incoerências](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/269089/101).

Um dos motivos que eu acho que uma ferramenta universal de AD não pode dar certo é que ela se tornaria algo próximo do UML, que já se mostrou mais um estorvo do que uma solução, e algumas pessoas já perceberam.

O AD precisa ser criado pensando em certas realidades e atender cenários mais ou menos parecidos. É possível fazer um AD para atender a maioria dos ERPs ou LOBs em geral, mas não para todos tipos de software, ele seria genérico demais, e daria muito trabalho para lidar com as especificidades, fora que seria complexo demais para poder ser flexível para tantos cenários, porque cada tipo de ativo novo pode exigir especificidades.

O ideal seria uma linguagem de programação e um ambiente feitos para lidar com um dicionário de aplicação, mas não acho que isso vá acontecer. Eu tenho uma ideia de algo assim, mas nunca sairá do papel porque exige muitos recursos para executá-lo. Nada que uma comunidade razoável ou uma grande empresa não possa suportar, mas daí a obter esse envolvimento vai uma distância.

Já me contestaram sobre o fato dessa solução de linguagem só funcionar no IDE, não ter um compilador e fluxo de trabalho tradicional, o que ele falhou em entender, e eu em explicar, é que a linguagem serve ao dicionário de aplicação, e a linguagem tradicional que analisa código normal que você conhece em si só cuida dos algoritmos, que são simples. A estrutura de dados, que é o complicado, é responsabilidade do AD, que só faz sentido existir no IDE, e os textos (códigos) dos algoritmos vão sendo anexados como ativos do software vinculados a outros ativos.

No catálogo você tem todo tipo de informação que serve ao software, tudo com organização avançada, exigindo você entender bem de taxonomia, provavelmente ontologia (menos para organizar, mas para definir melhor) para ficar bom, sem falar do uso da dialética para modelar corretamente, mas aí não tem a ver com a organização do catálogo e sim do projeto como um todo.

Existem ativos virtuais que servem mais ao processo do desenvolvimento e os concretos que acabarão de alguma forma no software em si, aquilo com que o usuário lidará diretamente.

Você pode ter todos os controles de repositório (de forma avançada e natural), *issues* de todo tipo, incluindo os PRs no AD, ter os documentos anexados que sustentam as decisões e servem de apoio no fluxo do trabalho, ou ter algumas das coisas que são típicas de UML. Enfim, o que for útil ao desenvolvimento pode ser colocado ali de forma organizada para "saltar aos olhos" sempre que for conveniente, até mesmo quando você não tem tanta ciência disso. Interligar esses ativos, até depois do fato, é fundamental para o completo sucesso do uso do AD. O que será incluso no SDK de AD depende da metodologia adotada.

Pode ter mecanismos que não são os dados, mas comportamentos no processo.
Pode colocar *continuous integration* por exemplo, ou testes (que ainda podem ser necessários, mas de uma forma diferente, estou deixando o termo bem aberto aqui).

Também terão ativos que são os pacotes, *namespaces*, módulos, tipos (classes, enumerações, estruturas, etc.), incluindo regras de uso que normalmente não se encontram em código normal. E esses tipos podem ser de várias naturezas, podendo representar dados no banco de dados, na aplicação, nos forms e relatórios, arquivos, rede, e outros mecanismos, além, é claro, das regras de negócio em si. Enfim, tudo o que está no software deve ser precisamente catalogado.

Sem um sistema de gerador de código ou o próprio código fazer adaptações necessárias em tempo de execução, você passa a ter duplicidade de esforços e consequente perda do DRY, o que ocasionará todos os problemas que temos hoje sem o AD. Não quer dizer que o AD fique completamente inútil, mas complica ver vantagem.

Você pode estar pensando que isso é inflexível, mas se for bem feito a flexibilidade é igual ao que você pode produzir com código direto, e de fato tudo o que é algoritmo continua tendo código normal. A estrutura de dados é que muda.

A forma como será implementado varia de acordo com as tecnologias que serão usadas como fundo do dicionário de dados. Vai usar C# ou Python? SQL ou NoSQL? Etc.

Fica fácil ver como tudo fica mais organizado, único, permite diversas composições, e tudo está "mais à mão". Tudo está ali, você não esquece de nada.

Todas mudanças podem ser propagadas só respondendo que quer a inclusão dentro de outros ativos (sendo que o campo já é um ativo mais granular), mas pode ser que precise de algum trabalho manual, auxiliado e acompanhado pelo AD para evitar fazer errado, ou para justificar porque não entrará em algum lugar que provavelmente deveria. Você automatiza as decisões. O campo deve entrar em todas as telas do sistema que usam essa entidade? De que forma em cada um? E os relatórios? E outras formas?

Se você começar pensar suas aplicações com o AD em mente, mesmo que não o implemente, já vai vendo quanto ele pode mudar a forma de fazer software. Muitos dos problemas que você enfrenta, o que acha que poderia fazer diferente, o que acha repetitivo e chato, passível de erro, provavelmente seria diferente com o AD.

E o futuro pode ser melhor com a inteligência artificial por aí. IA só funciona quando você tem uma base de dados muito grande e bem modelada para tomar decisões, o AD ajuda muito nisso.

Facilita documentar as APIs e manter sua estabilidade, evitando mudar algo que não pode, sem querer.

Uma [boa fonte para começar entender o AD é ver como os dados são armazenados em banco de dados](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metadata_repository), daí estenda os ativos para qualquer coisa do sistema e não só do banco de dados.

Outra ideia complementar é o [espectro semântico](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_spectrum). Não que ele ajude definir o AD melhor, mas dá alguma ideia de como pode ser um modelo de AD.

É comum que ativos do AD adotem estratégias de cascata. Em algumas tecnologias isso acaba evitando herança até mesmo em mecanismos onde ela sempre foi consagrada.

Só para listar alguns tipos de ativos possíveis:

- bases de dados
- tabelas lógicas
- tabelas físicas
- diretórios
- colunas
- índices
- gatilhos
- enumerações
- valores padrão
- tipos
- papéis
- restrições
- validações
- relações
- eventos
- notificações
- lookups
- transações
- versões
- famílias
- atividades
- tarefas
- arquivos
- menus
- páginas
- formulários
- abas
- campos
- controles diversos
- relatórios
- gráficos
- sessões
- mensagens padrões
- scripts
- funções
- valores
- entidades
- agendamentos
- contas
- usuários
- identidades
- atribuições
- alçadas
- parametrizações
- questionamentos
- seleções
- tabelas de dados diversos
- linguagens
- formatos
- localizações
- globalização
- metadados diversos
- privilégios
- auditorias
- perfilamentos
- contextos
- módulos
- subsistemas
- agregadores
- políticas
- estratégias
- regras
- exceções (não é sobre `Exception`, que está dentro de tipos)
- prioridades
- fluxos de trabalho
- fachadas
- fábricas
- descritivos
- tickets
- to-dos
- documentos
- clientes
- infra
- camadas
- APIs externas de entrada
- APIs externas de saída
- importações
- exportações
- processos
- etc.

Em algumas coisas dá pra granular mais, fazer mapeamentos e amarrações, coloquei só exemplos mesmo. Dá para perceber que tem muito do DB, de GUI, de domínios comuns, de *design patterns*, etc., tudo de uma forma diferente do que se codifica hoje. Acho que deu para perceber um padrão do que pode ser colocado. Eu só toquei a superfície e depende de cada caso, por isso eu acho que tentar fazer um AD que atenda tudo não dá muito certo. Se pareceu muito, saiba que ERPs costumam ter muitos milhares de ativos, até mesmo milhões em alguns casos.

Eu tenho pouca experiência fazendo o AD cuidar até dos mecanismos, por isso não sei o quanto continua sendo útil nessa parte.

## Exemplo real

Pra mostrar um exemplo (não estou assinando embaixo como boa implementação) fica aqui o [RADICORE](https://www.radicore.org/). Tem uns ERPs *open source* (não gosto de todos eles) que usam um sistema de dicionários dados e podem ser inspecionados, mas eles fazem tudo de forma bem superficial, e o ganho não é tão grande. Me parece que todos usam como marketing. O [Adempiere é um exemplo](http://www.adempiere.com/Application_Dictionary). Tem umas [tentativas acidentais modernas](http://labs.infyom.com/laravelgenerator/).

## Conclusão

Eu queria analisar como o AD se dá em cenários diferentes, por exemplo de desenvolvimento de jogos.

Não é uma ferramenta para todos os casos e que pode ser usada em todos cenários, mas onde pode o ganho pode ser substancial. Falo de custo, simplicidade, facilidade de manutenção, confiabilidade no que está fazendo, aderência às necessidades do cliente/usuário, além de tornar mais previsível.

O uso errado pode ser trágico, como qualquer ferramenta. O abuso do aprofundamento dele pode começar a trazer mais custos que benefícios. Pode ser complicado ou custoso aprofundar mais depois.

A mudança de paradigma é brutal, mas só assim para ter um grande ganho. Por isso as pessoas têm medo dele.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).

Comment: O que gosto do Stack Overflow é perguntas que te fazem pensar. Esta pode ter me ajudado definir melhor o termo, e lamento se lá o termo foi usado de forma descuidada, a culpa não é bem minha :) Pra melhorar tenho que cortar alguma coisa, bateu no limite :)

Comment: Uau, quando você disse que a resposta seria longa você não estava brincando! Hehe... Levarei um tempo até ler todas as referências externas e compreender melhor o conceito, mas, muito obrigado desde já, será bem útil! :-)