# Qual é o local correto para armazenar as mensagens de validação em um projeto .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, string, desempenho, validação

Estou criando uma classe relativamente simples, mas incluí algumas validações em suas propriedades.

```
public class Sala : EntidadeBase
    {
        #region Enums

        public enum StatusSala
        {
            Disponivel,
            Reservada,
            Inativa,
            Bloqueada
        };

        #endregion

        #region Propriedades

        public string Nome { get; private set; }
        public int Capacidade { get; private set; }
        public StatusSala Status { get; private set; }

        #endregion

        #region Contrutores

        public Sala(string nome, int capacidade, StatusSala status) : base()
        {
            SetNome(nome);
            SetCapacidade(capacidade);
            SetStatus(status);
        }

        #endregion

        #region Métodos

        #region SettersPrivados

        private void SetNome(string nome)
        {
            ValidacaoDominio.Validar()
                .Quando(string.IsNullOrEmpty(nome), "O nome não pode ser vazio")
                .Quando(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(nome) && nome.Length < 3, "o nome deve ter pelo menos 3 caracteres")
                .DispararValidacao();

            Nome = nome;
        }

        private void SetCapacidade(int capacidade)
        {
            ValidacaoDominio.Validar()
                .Quando(capacidade < 1, "Capacidade da sala Inválida")
                .DispararValidacao();

            Capacidade = capacidade;
        }

        private void SetStatus(StatusSala status)
        {
            ValidacaoDominio.Validar()
            .Quando(!Enum.TryParse(typeof(StatusSala), status.ToString(), out var retorno), "Status Inválido")
                .DispararValidacao();

            Status = status;
        }

        #endregion

        #region Publicos

        public void AlterarNome(string nomeAlterado)
        {
            SetNome(nomeAlterado);
        }

        public void AlterarCapacidade(int capacidadeAlterada)
        {
            SetCapacidade(capacidadeAlterada);
        }

        public void AlterarStatus(StatusSala statusAlterado)
        {
            SetStatus(statusAlterado);
        }

        #endregion

        #endregion
```

Por uma questão de organização, não gostaria de deixar uma *string* fixa nas mensagens de validação, pois algumas podem ser repetidas (exemplo: Nome inválido. Isso pode ser referenciado para qualquer entidade que possua a propriedade Nome) e a possibilidade de fugir do padrão é grande.

Até aonde sei, posso fazer isso via *resources* ou criar uma classe auxiliar para concentrar essas mensagens.

Inicialmente, concentrei as mensagens em classes estáticas, separando-as por categorias (das mais gerais para as mais especificas), mas nada impede de fazer de outra forma.

Classe para mensagens "gerais":

```
public class GeralMsgs
    {
        public const string NomeInvalido = "O Nome é invalido";
        public const string NomeMenorTresCaracteres = "O nome deve ter pelo menos três caracteres";
    }
```

Classe para mensagens especifica da classe `Sala`:

```
    public class SalaMsgs
    {
        public const string CapacidadeInvalida = "A capacidade  da sala é inválida";
        public const string StatusInvalido = "O status da sala é inválido ";
    }
```

Dessa forma, as validações iriam referenciar as constantes

```
ValidacaoDominio.Validar()
                .Quando(string.IsNullOrEmpty(nome), GeralMsgs.NomeInvalido)
                .Quando(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(nome) && nome.Length < 3, GeralMsgs.NomeMenorTresCaracteres)
                .DispararValidacao();
...
ValidacaoDominio.Validar()
                .Quando(capacidade < 1, SalaMsgs.CapacidadeInvalida)
                .DispararValidacao();
...
 ValidacaoDominio.Validar()
            .Quando(!Enum.TryParse(typeof(StatusSala), status.ToString(), out var retorno), SalaMsgs.StatusInvalido)
                .DispararValidacao();
```

Do ponto de vista de saúde da aplicação, pensando em escalabilidade e boas práticas, qual é o local correto para concentrar essa mensagens? Deixo dessa forma ou jogo tudo para um arquivo *resource* do projeto ou tanto faz?

Meu objetivo é sempre tentar fazer da melhor maneira possível, mas sem criar uma arma de raio laser para matar uma formiga, mas também não quero no futuro olhar para o 147 que o Maniero sempre posta e perceber que minha aplicação ou meu *mindset* me levou para o "Importante é funcionar".

Comment: _"147 que o Maniero sempre posta"_ o que é 147?

Comment: https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fiat_147

Comment: kkk o fiat 147 que representa "funcionar é diferente de estar certo"  ->https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/422626/69359

Comment: eu desde o inicio que sempre usei [esta livraria](https://fluentvalidation.net/) e nunca mais validei nada com tantas linhas de código como mostra :) é simples, cada class fica com a seu validador, ajuda a manutencao no futuro...

Comment: @balexandre, eu troquei a validação atual por esse approach, mas usando o Notifique-me, que é um pacote baseado no Flunt, do Andre Baltieri, mas continuo com o mesmo problema que é buscar onde devo incluir as mensagens de validação.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nem sempre é fácil responder essas coisas. Eu mesmo já fiz de formas diferentes. Hoje eu gosto de fazer de uma forma que eu nem indico porque precisa uma certa cancha pra fazer certo que é o uso de geração de código. Tudo o que é dado da aplicação e pode ter uma flexibilidade e precisa de um controle centralizado eu coloco no banco de dados e gero código para dar eficiência, o que é conhecido como [dicionário de dados](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/347190/101) (agora tenho preferido o termo dicionário de aplicação por ser algo mais amplo) que não é famoso então ninguém aprende usar.

Fazendo de um jeito mais tradicional e se não precisa ter essa flexibilidade de trocar as mensagens de acordo com a instalação então o uso de *resource* não é indicado. Aí eu faria mais ou menos como está fazendo. Mas não tenho todas informações para tomar a melhor decisão, sempre pode ter um detalhe, até pequeno, que pode fazer eu mudar de ideia.

Não gosto muito de ter uma classe de mensagens para a classe principal, em geral acho que as mensagens deveriam estar nela mesmo. Uma geral pode fazer sentido. Pode ter certos agrupamentos, aí vai complicando, começa ser difícil saber onde colocar. Por isso que eu prefiro o banco de dados, dá flexibilidade.

Pode ser interessante ter um mecanismo mais sofisticado para pegar as mensagens do que constantes, mas tem que analisar a questão mais profundamente.

Algumas pessoas gostam de abstrair a forma para poder trocar o detalhe de implementação depois, e pode ser uma boa (quando faço geração de código eu tenho isso sem perder eficiência). Se fizer isto não importa de onde vem a mensagem, se é *resource*, banco de dados, uma fonte própria, variáveis ou constantes e onde está a mensagem. Tem caso que abstração piora a legibilidade do código, mas se for para obter flexibilidade não tem jeito. É fazer a tal da [indireção](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181032/101).

Qualquer indireção traz um custo, até uma simples constante, precisa provar o ganho.

**Pode** estar abusando da abstração para evitar o [número mágico](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/135108/101).

Todo padrão a se aplicar vira antipadrão se errar na dose.

Não é fácil lidar com isso adequadamente, então se não tiver uma vantagem muito clara pode ser melhor nem fazer algo assim, e deixar as mensagens normais como é padrão.

Eu não sei se esse cuidado todo é tão necessário. Pode ser, não sei seu contexto, não vejo muita gente fazendo (mas não é argumento, podem estar fazendo errado, mas minha percepção é que não precisa tanto assim). **Talvez** o problema seja tentar fazer com todas mensagens e não apenas alguns casos que façam mais sentido.

Já parou pra pensar que se as pessoas usarem errado pode não resolver nada ou piorar? Se fizerem certo esse mecanismo talvez seja canhão para matar passarinho e aí sai certo de forma mais simples.

Me concentrei na questão das mensagens, a mecânica da validação me parece fora de escopo da pergunta, mas vejo muita gente seguindo receitas que parecem ajudar mas a pessoa nunca viu ganho real e tem problemas que ela nem percebe. Eu gosto de abstrações que trazem vantagem, mas vejo abusos direto.

## Manter equilíbrio

A sua preocupação de manter o equilíbrio é louvável, mas também não dá para fazer isto se procurar uma fórmula única que resolva tudo, este é talvez o maior erro que todo desenvolvedor comete hoje em dia. As pessoas não querem fazer o que é mais adequado, querem aprender uma forma e fazer sempre assim. Por isso tem tanta coisa com problema e funciona apesar de não estar certo.

Dentro deste ponto é importante notar que a busca pela perfeição já é uma forma de fazer errado. Sistemas devem resolver problemas, não é aceitável abusar das gambiarras, fazer de qualquer jeito, não ter preocupações, mas também tentar fazer academicamente correto já é um erro do ponto de vista de engenharia. Tem que levar em consideração custo, esforço, e outros problemas que isso pode acarretar, que nem sempre é fácil prever. Depende de experiência.

O erro faz parte do processo de desenvolvimento. Vai errar uma vez, verá o que aconteceu, tentará arrumar e não cometer o mesmo erro na próxima, ainda que cometa outro. Um bom engenheiro vai acumulando essas experiências e fará cada vez melhor. Um mau engenheiro pode até não cometer o mesmo erro na próxima, mas cometerá outro, provavelmente oposto, tentando evitar um erro que aprendeu. Ou seja, a pessoa é seguidora de receita de bolo, ela sempre faz algo que aprendeu sem entender quando aplicar, sem pensar em todas questões. Isto é tão comum hoje em dia que já se tornou raro encontrar quem não faz assim.

Comment: Upvote e marcar como resposta é muito pouco pra esse tipo de resposta....
Esse projeto em sí é só para estudos, mas analisando melhor a sua resposta, o cenário como um todo e pensando na flexibilidade, creio que deixar no Resources é o melhor caminho, já que eu consigo fazer os testes de unidade sem depender do banco(o que poderia ser uma solução interessante também, mas aí teria que mockar as mensagens no meus testes) e de certa forma a ferramenta que uso hoje (.NET) já está preparada para usar o Resources, então o esforço para flexibilizar é muito menor do que eu buscar inventar algo...

Answer (score 1):

Eu tenho feito toda a validação de domínio através de **Exceptions** com tipos específicos para cada Entidade (ou Aggregate Root se estivermos falando de DDD).

Dessa forma, fica fácil inclusive de implementar traduções para outros idiomas no futuro, pois as Exceptions recebem apenas os valores, e não a mensagem explícita.

Por exemplo:

```c#
public class SalaException: Exception
{
    private SalaException (string message)
       : base(message)
    { }

    public static SalaException CapacidadeDaSalaInvalida() 
    {
        return new SalaException("Capacidade da sala Inválida");
    }

    public static SalaException NomeDaSalaNaoInformado() 
    {
        return new SalaException("O nome não pode ser vazio.");
    }

    public static SalaException NomeDaSalaInsuficiente(string nome) 
    {
        return new SalaException($"Nome inválido ({nome}). O nome deve ter pelo menos 3 caracteres");
    }

    public static SalaException StatusDaSalaInvalido(string status) 
    {
        return new SalaException($"Status Inválido: {status}");
    }
}

public class Sala : EntidadeBase
{
    public string Nome { get; private set; }
    public int Capacidade { get; private set; }
    public StatusSala Status { get; private set; }

    public Sala(string nome, int capacidade, StatusSala status) : base()
    {
        SetNome(nome);
        SetCapacidade(capacidade);
        SetStatus(status);
    }

    private void SetNome(string nome)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(nome))
            throw SalaException.NomeDaSalaNaoInformado();

        if (nome.Length < 3)
            throw SalaException.NomeDaSalaInsuficiente();           

        Nome = nome;
    }

    private void SetCapacidade(int capacidade)
    {
        if (capacidade < 1)
            throw SalaException.CapacidadeDaSalaInvalida(1);

        Capacidade = capacidade;
    }

    private void SetStatus(StatusSala status)
    {       
        if (!Enum.TryParse(typeof(StatusSala), status.ToString(), out var retorno)) 
            throw SalaException.StatusDaSalaInvalido(status.ToString());

        Status = status;
    }
}
```

Comment: A solução é até interessante, mas levando em consideração a possibilidade de tradução, o que não é o meu caso, deixar as mensagens da forma que você está deixando não está abrindo motivos para uma alteração nas suas classes? 
Eu troquei as validações e agora estou usando um pacote que implementa a Notification  Pattern, dessa forma deixo o meu código bem mais limpo.